# How to access a closure function in a require.js module?

Tags: requirejs, closures

I am trying to use **require.js** to load my modules dependencies and so far it is working, but I have a doubt. I've created a little function to test the modules and placed it in a file called *panelTest.js*:

```
define(['./panel/View', './panel/TitleView'], function(View, TitleView) {

    return function test(container) {

        // main view
        var panel = new View(container, 'main');
        var panelTitle = new TitleView(panel.getContainer(), 'main-title');
        panelTitle.setTitle('Properties Panel');
        //panelTitle.addCss('pjs-panelTitle');
        panel.addView(panelTitle);

        // sections
        var top = new View(panel.getContainer(), 'top');
        panel.addView(top);
        var middle = new View(panel.getContainer(), 'middle');
        panel.addView(middle);
        var bottom = new View(panel.getContainer(), 'bottom');
        panel.addView(bottom);

    };
});
```

In the html that uses the modules I included this script tag as shown in the [require.js documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) to load *panelTest.js*.

```
<script data-main="panelTest.js"
    src="require.js"></script>
```

My question is **how can I call the test function from outside the module**, since the *container* parameter it is supposed to come from outside the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the module through the appropriate channels provided by RequireJS. You could do it like this in a `script` tag that appears after the one that loads RequireJS:

```
require(['panelTest'], function (panelTest) {
  panelTest(/* some value */);
});
```

Given the code you show, your `panelTest` module does not seem to really make sense as a "main module" so I would not put it as `data-main`.

If you want to use it from anther module, put the module in its own file and define it like this:

```
define(['panelTest'], function (panelTest) {
  panelTest(/* some value */);
});
```